# Dynamic DOM elements creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I should add rows to the table with jQuery:

```
    <table class="table">
      <tbody id="dh-values">
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I've written the following code:

```
  function displayHash(fieldName) {
    $('#dh-values').append('<tr></tr>').append('<td id="dh-'+fieldName+'">'+$('#'+fieldName).val()+'</td>').append('<td id="dh-'+fieldName+'-h">'+hex_sha1($('#'+fieldName).val())+'</td>');
  };
```

But it looks awful. Is there any way to simplify that?

Comment: You are actually appending the `td`s to `tbody`

Comment: You only need one `.append()` call. You can build the entire string of `<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>` and append it once. It isn't necessarily prettier though.

Comment: It looks awful because you're "chaining". Separate each method call onto a new line. The snippet could also use some variables.

Comment: @Esailija, I've checked the code generated, it is correct - `<tbody><tr><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody>`

Comment: @LA_ not in here http://jsfiddle.net/EsEZD/

Comment: @Esailija, I see the problem now - http://jsfiddle.net/EsEZD/1/ returns `<tbody id="dh-values"><tr></tr><td></td></tbody>`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combined answer of Esalija, amnotiam et al

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/wRTHs/)

```
function displayHash(fieldID) {
    var val = $('#'+fieldID).val();
    var valSha = hex_sha1(val);
    $("<tr>").appendTo("#dh-values")
       .append('<td id="dh-'+fieldID+'">'+val+'</td>')
       .append('<td id="dh-'+fieldID+'-h">'+valSha+'</td>');
};
```

Comment: still appending to the `tbody` though

Comment: `.append` returns the jQuery object it operates on

Comment: Almost. If this function is called more than once, you'll be selecting all `tr` elements every time. You only want the new one.

Comment: so now it appends to all `tr`?

Comment: You could do with `$("<tr>").appendTo("#dh-values").append("td stuff here")`

Comment: @Esailija's solution is better. You shouldn't need to do DOM selection for an element you just created.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/exopoc/edit#javascript,html,live

```
function displayHash(fieldName) {

  var cont = '<tr><td id="dh-'+ fieldName +'">'+ fieldName +'</td> <td id="dh-'+ fieldName +'-h">'+ fieldName +'</td></tr>';
  $(cont).appendTo('#dh-values');

}



displayHash('12345678');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [client side templating engine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_templates) to separate html structure and business logic for manipulating the data to be binded with template in javascript.